# Angular JS - Retrieve URL parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the correct Angular approach to retrieving the URL parameters?

Example: http://example.com/mypage.html?product=1234&region=4&lang=en

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question with more details, and found a perfect response. Please see DavidL's response in my question here:

[Reading URL parameters in AngularJS - A simple way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867483/reading-url-parameters-in-angularjs-a-simple-way)

Thanks to everyone who assisted me in this thread; perhaps I didn't include enough details in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

This will convert your query into an object

```
var queryData = url.split('?')[url.split('?').length - 1].split('&').reduce(function(prev, curr){
    var fieldName = curr.split('=')[0]; 
    var value = curr.split('=').length > 1 ? curr.split('=')[1] : '';
    prev[fieldName] = value; 
    return prev
}, {});
```

And then you can access them by queryData.product, for example. 
Not angular, but it's a solution.

For the angular way, you can use $location.search() as described here http://www.angulartutorial.net/2015/04/get-url-parameter-using-angular-js.html

Comment: Hi @TitusPopovici. Same question as well. This, only seems to work if my URL ends with #/ as in example.com/mypage.html#/?product=1234&region=4&lang=en. Do you know if there is a workaround for this? The latter does not feel like a typical URL.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, for the angular way. You could make your own angular service that uses the function I wrote above for url's that are not angular routes (with the #/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $location service. For example:

```js
angular.module('parameters', []).run(['$location',
  function($location) {
    var params = $location.search();
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks @roger. This only seems to work if my URL ends with #/ as in  http://example.com/mypage.html#/?product=1234&region=4&lang=en. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Are you usinge html5Mode? Because that your URL doesn't have the prefix "#/"?
"$location.search();" works on html5Mode on the same way.

If not, your parameters always have to be after "#/" prefix, this is the angular way, your URL will always be completed with "#/".

Comment: Thanks @roger. I read about html5mode, and even saw the documentation, but I'm super confused on how to implement this. It says to use $locationProvider, but where do I set this? Would it be in the controller? Because I would need it to take effect globally

Comment: You should use the config function of your module (angular.module('parameters', []).config(...))