# Reading URL parameters in AngularJS - A simple way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to Angular here. I come from a PHP and ASP background, where the way we read parameters is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var foo = <?php echo $_GET['foo']; ?>;
        var bar = <?php echo $_GET['bar']; ?>;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('Foo is: ' + foo + ' and bar is: ' + bar);
        });
    </script>
<head>
```

(It's not complete code, but you get the idea -- very simple)

I've never done "client-side" query parsing before. What is the correct method? I've posted a question in the past, but I'm not getting any answers. Google searching is not helping either.

My URL is typically is in the form of: example.com?foo=123&bar=456

Is the above syntax not supported these days? Should I be doing something like: example.com/foo/123/bar/345 instead?

I'm willing to change my URL structure for something that works cleanly with Angular, but need to be pointed in the right direction. For example, I've heard of ngRoute, but I have no idea where to even start. Is this the correct approach?

I've posted a question in the past, but didn't get much help, so I'm re-posting this with more information so that it's more clear.

Thanks for any pointers.

### Edit - using $location

Note, I've tried using $location, but I this has been unsuccessful for me. See code below:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', ['$location', MyController]);

function MyController($location) {
    var params = $location.search();

    alert('foo is: ' + params.foo + ' and bar is: ' + params.bar);
}
```

Note: I've read something about setting $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) in order to get this style of query parsing to work; however, I've been unsuccessful with this too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string using Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/get-query-string-using-angularjs)

Comment: Use $routeParams https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: @Johan this requires a reference to ngRoute and the OP never said that they are using ngRoute.

Comment: He also didnt say that he is not using it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can inject the `$location` service if you are using html5 mode.

Because you are using URLs without a base root (such as a ! or a #), you need to explicitly add a `<base>` tag that defines the "root" of your application OR you can configure `$locationProvider` to not require a base tag.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ParamsCtrl as vm">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    // or

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });    
}]);

app.controller("TestCtrl", ['$location', function($location) {
    var params = $location.search();
    alert('Foo is: ' + params.foo + ' and bar is: ' + params.bar);
});
```

It is worth noting that you can add a router library such as ngRoute, ui-router or the new, unfinished component router.  These routers rely on a base route off of a symbol (! or #) and define everything after the symbol as a client-side route which gets controlled by the router.  This will allow your Angular app to function as a Single Page App and will give you access to $routeParams or the ui-router equivalent.

Comment: WORKS LIKE A CHARM! THANK YOU! @DavidL. I've been scratching my head over this for too long! So this is the URL structure that I've always accustom to. However, I feel that this is not the "angular" way of doing things and that it's primarily here for compatibility. Do you have any comments on this?

Comment: Glad it worked!  My personal preference is to use a router library of some sort.  I've used ngRoute with plenty of success, using # for backwards compatibility.  If you do something along those lines, You will no longer need to do these base/locationprovider backwards compatibility hacks, including no longer needing html5Mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$location.search()`.

```
var parameters = $location.search();

console.log(parameters);
-> object{
    foo: foovalue,
    bar: barvalue
   }
```

SO these values will be accessible with `parameters.foo` and  `parameters.bar`